# PostgreSQL Installation interrupted if user provide non English password

Tags: postgresql, passwords

It seems that `superuser` password can't accept non-English characters?

Comment: all sets can be used: [https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/multibyte.html](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/multibyte.html)

Comment: What installer are you using, and on what platform?

Comment: We are using postgresql-9.6.2-2-windows-x64. And if we provide any non english password, installation interrupting.

Comment: Dos command for for reference:  postgresql-9.6.2-2-windows-x64.exe --unattendedmodeui none --mode unattended --superpassword Télécharger --servicename "PostgreSQL" --servicepassword Télécharger --disable-stackbuilder yes --serverport 7555

Answer (score 0):

no - utf passwords are quite OK for postgres:

```
t=# create user so superuser password 'де́льта, греч. δέλτα)';
CREATE ROLE
Time: 112.705 ms
t=# \q
MacBook-Air:~ vao$ export PGPASSWORD="де́льта, греч. δέλτα)" && psql -h 192.168.8.110 t -U so
Timing is on.
psql (9.6.1, server 9.6.3)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

t=# \q
```

Comment: While true, this doesn't mean the installer they're using will cope.

Comment: Right, I just never hit such problem. Thank you for comment

Comment: selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... windows
creating configuration files ... ok
creating template1 database in C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/data/base/1... ok
initializing pg_authid ... ok
setting password ... FATAL:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe0 0x74 0x27
child process exited with exit code 1
initdb: removing contents of data directory "C:/Program
Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/data"
Called Die(Failed to initialise the database cluster with initdb)...
Failed to initialise the database cluster with initdb

Comment: yeah - I have no experience with Windows. why not setting ascii password on installation and after finishing, setting it to utf value?.. just to avoid possible utf problem with installator

Comment: Same issue for me also , any help